# Test UV protection on sunglasses

Tags: glasses, sun-exposure, uv-rays, sunlight

I bought sunglasses in China that claims to have UV400 protection.
I'd like to test this as my eyes' health is on the line :)

Is there any way to check the maximum UV amount these glasses can protect me against ?

Thanks, .x

Comment: I don't see how this is a medical question. I doubt if any physician knows how to test sunglasses for UV protection, but optical engineers and physicists probably do. I think you'd have better luck asking this in engineering or physics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a medical question.

Comment: @CareyGregory I'm interested in the answer, so I posted it on the Physics SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369916/testing-uva-and-uvb-protection-in-sunglasses